# I'm trying to edit a datatable on a SQL server and i keep getting an error about either not accepting a keyword or not connecting due to a timeout

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, connection-timeout

I need to be able to view a table and the select a row from that table and edit a field in that row for a project I'm working on. Right now I'm just using a proof of concept program to figure out how it works so i can implement it into the real thing. So the first error i get is the server not recognizing the keyword "provider"

```
protected void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DevTesting SET testStr = @testStr, testStr2 = @testStr2, testStr3 = @testStr3, testNum = @testNum WHERE PersonID = @PersonID";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        string strPersonID = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
        string strTestStr1 = "aerhtsm";   
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@testStr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strTestStr1;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridView(); 

}

private void BindGridView()
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer2005DBConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        DataSet grid1 = new DataSet();
        string strSelectCmd = "SELECT testStr, testStr2, testStr3, testNum FROM GridView1";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(grid1, "GridView1");
        DataView dvPerson = grid1.Tables["GridView1"].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataSource = grid1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The other error I'm getting is that the connection keeps timing out when the code reaches the *conn.Open();* in the changeButton method. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong. Heres a copy of my web.config file in case you need it.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <configuration>
   <configSections>

   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication11-20130731142716;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication11-20130731142716.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     <add name="TestConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=HQSQL;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=BG_BACKUP"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
      <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=HQSQL;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=BG_BACKUP"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
     </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
  </controls>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
  </system.web>
 <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
       <parameters>
     <parameter value="v11.0" />
     </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
      </configuration>
```

Ok here is a [image](http://gyazo.com/12af35464364adb35e74c142e40fe08b) of the error I get when I push the button to overwrite a part of the datatable. I tried to remedie the solution on my own and got another similar error which is in the [second image.](http://gyazo.com/cc7ee6a6cac14a9e491cb1f12499d3f7)

Comment: Where is `SQLServer2005DBConnectionString` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The **ConnectionString** key in the connectionString section of your web.config is used for an `SqlClient.SqlConnection` but you specify to use `providerName="System.Data.OleDb"`. You should change to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` The OleDb client cannot understand that syntax.

Then the UPDATE command uses 5 parameters, but you add only one to the Parameters collection. This will be another error, after the opening of the connection.

Then in BindGridView you use a connectionstring not defined anywhere, finally the SELECT statement here refers to a table named GridView, I suspect that you have mistyped the correct name of the table (the one used in the update command is called `DevTesting` )

For the timeout problem you should add the exception message connected to the timeout